# Behavior of an integral close to $x=0$

Tags: real-analysis, definite-integrals, asymptotics, taylor-expansion, banach-spaces

**Question**: Consider
$$
v(x)\equiv {(1-e^{-2x})^n}\int_x^\infty \frac{f(x')dx'}{(1-e^{-2x'})^{n+1}e^{x'}},\;\;\;\;n>0.
$$
where $f\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^+)\cap C^1(\mathbb{R}^+)$. I want to prove that
$\displaystyle{\lim_{x\rightarrow 0+}\!v}$ exists.

**Context**: I am computing the resolvent set of a differential operator and I computed the solution of the resolvent equation. Using variation of parameters, I end up with expressions similar to what is above. If you want to do it with a specific $f$ if you prefer, then that would work. You could do it with $f(x)=e^{-x}$ for example, without computing the integral explicitly though.

**Reasoning**: When $x\rightarrow 0^+$, I can see it is fine. However, I am just not sure what to formally use to establish the result I can see is true. That is, I can see that the integral will behave like $x^{-n}$ as  $x\rightarrow 0+$. Thus its "bad" behavior will be cancelled by the term in front and $v$ will exist at $x=0$.